# Migrate git repo from Google Code to Github

Tags: git, github, google-code

I have a git project hosted on Google Code. I'd like to move it to Github, with the revision history included. I don't use the ticket system so that won't matter.

In similar questions like mine, the problem is migrating from a SVN repo in Google Code to Github. I'm already using git.

I have the project checked out on my machine because I'm developing on it. From what I understood from git, my local project already includes the full history because of its distributed nature. So maybe copying it to github is really simple, but I don't know the steps.

Of course the idea is that new changes will be pushed to Github and the Google code repository would remain frozen.

Comment: Have you seen this article from Github about migrating? https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-subversion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a github repository, and make sure your SSH key, etc... is installed properly.

Check out your repository from google.

Run:

```
git remote add github <URL FROM GITHUB>
git push github HEAD
```

That will push your current branch.  You can push others by switching to them and repeating the `git push github HEAD`  (or other, more advanced ways).

Answer (score 3):

On Github create an empty repository, push your local repository to it -- done.

At that point if you want all future pushes to go to Github, change the `origin` remote to point to the Github repository instead of the one at Google Code -- or you can clone a new working repository from Github.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Code export to GitHub feature](https://code.google.com/export-to-github/).